# Cannot access Google Analytics after Google Apps upgrade

Tags: google-workspace, google-analytics

I have been using my company email address as an account to access Google Analytics for the past 3 years. Recently, I migrated our company email addresses to the Google Apps system and if I remember correctly, Google noticed that a name@company.com email address already existed and did I want to convert/merge these accounts together - which I said yes to. I did not think what the side effects of this action would lead to, but as of today I cannot access my analytics data using the same login and password I have used for the past 3 years!

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Visit: http://analytics.google.com/ and login using these details:
Username: user%domain.com@gtempaccount.com 
Password: your password

E.g. if before you migrated to apps, you used to login into analytics with john@example.com, then use: john%example.com@gtempaccount.com

If you can't remember the password, use the usual Forgot Password routine.
Once in, you will be able to see your old stuff and Google will guide you accordingly regarding resolving the conflicted accounts etc.

Answer (score 1):

Fill out the form here:

http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/request.py?contact_type=regain_access

There used to be [another form that you could try](https://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/viewform?formkey=dGRvcXVVNU5HbXhSSldRNU5LWVR6Vmc6MQ&ndplr=1), but it's been turned off. Probably because it delivered results.

Finally, you can try emailing analytics-support@google.com but that has not delivered good results for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You need to speak to the IT Dept at your company; Google Apps accounts linked to a company can have access to individual Google Applications configured by the IT Department of that company.

EDIT: Reading your question again, I'm not sure if you are the IT Dept. If you are, then go to the Google Apps for Domain Control Panel https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/[YOURDOMAIN]
Click on Organisation & Users. Then Services, and scroll down to enable Analytics again.

Comment: Hello,

Yes I am the 'IT Department' (small company). Just looked in the control panel and it was already activated.  I'm afraid I may have lost 3 years of analytic data because I said yes to 'merging' the accounts. *(Don't think merging is the correct terminology, but when I tried to add my own name@ address to google apps it said somebody was already using that address - please log in to verify you are the owner etc).*

I am still getting weekly analytic reports via my email so they still exist somewhere!